# LookupSource must be connected to TTable component

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tclientdataset, data-aware, tcombobox

I'm attempting to use a TDBLookupCombo, but am getting an error "EInvalidOperation with message 'LookupSource must be connected to TTable component'.

I have the TDBLookupCombo.LookupSource connected to a TDataSource. The TDataSource.Dataset is pointing to a TClientDataSet which contains the records for the lookup table (Fields ID and Description).

```
LookupDisplay := 'Description';
LookupField := 'ID';
LookupSource := dsLookup;
```

Is this not possible to do since TCilentDataSet isn't a descendant of TTable? If so then what would be the best alternative without using 3rd party components.

Comment: I don't have a `TDBLookupCombo` in my component palette. I have a `TDBLookupComboBox`, which does not have the properties `LookupDisplay`, `LookupField`, or `LookupSource`. Are you using one of the old BDE controls by mistake? TTable doesn't exist outside the BDE.

Comment: You're correct. Man I feel like a bozo!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*TDBLookupCombo* is one of the old BDE-based data controls, which is why it's dependent on connecting to a *TTable*.

It seems you should be using `TDBLookupComboBox` instead, which works fine connected to a *TDataSource* which is attached to any bi-directional *TDataSet* descendant (which includes *TClientDataSet*).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code...Nope you can't do that, descends to TDataSet...TClientDataSet -> TCustomClientDataSet -> TDataSet

```
procedure TDBLookupList.SetLookupSource(Value: TDataSource);
begin
  if (Value <> nil) and ((Value = DataSource) or
    ((Value.DataSet <> nil) and (Value.DataSet = FFieldLink.DataSet))) then
    raise EInvalidOperation.Create(SLookupSourceError);
  if (Value <> nil) and (Value.DataSet <> nil) and
    not (Value.DataSet.InheritsFrom(TTable)) then
    raise EInvalidOperation.Create(SLookupTableError);
  inherited DataSource := Value;
  NewLayout;
end;
```

hmmm...Free...check out Jedi components...maybe TJvDBLookupComboEdit

Comment: Thanks, but it turns out I should have been using a TDBLookupComboBox, that does exactly what I need.

Comment: While your answer is technically correct, it doesn't solve the actual problem, which is the use of the wrong control. :-)

Comment: Yeah...don't use many of the delphi db controls...mostly Woll to Woll or TMS...so just went to the source.  Yeah thought it weird that it was coupled to TTable...hadn't seen problems like that in ages. ;)